# Why can't we copy a child theme in Shopware 6?

Tags: themes, shopware6

We are using a purchased theme (Horzion PRO) and created a sub theme as per their guide to make some small adjustments.

Now we need to create several sales channels which should have basically the same design, include those adjustments, but have changes in colors and so on.

Those colors can be changed in the Shopware admin panel. So we usually would create a duplicate via the admin panel to create a different customization data set (is this what this function does?)

[image: Duplicate theme]

Unfortunately the duplicate theme function is <strike>grayed out</strike> missing for the Child theme.

What is the technical reason for this? Is this fixable?

We know one workaround would be to copy&paste the child them 5 times, but we'd rather like to avoid this also having future updates in mind.

We are currently on Shopware 6.4 but can upgrade to 6.5 if there is any improvement in this regards.

Answer (score 2):

Is it only grayed out on the child theme or in general? This would suggest that the menu option is disabled. Looking at the [template](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ea26c19ef62039ce6a3887522e7d6caa65e95582/src/Storefront/Resources/app/administration/src/modules/sw-theme-manager/page/sw-theme-manager-list/sw-theme-manager-list.html.twig#L147) the option is only disabled if the user is missing the corresponding role permission `theme.creator`. I can't see any other reason, why the option should be disabled otherwise.

If all fails you can simply create the new record in the `theme` table yourself. For reference this is the code that creates the new record where `parentTheme` is the theme to be duplicated.

```js
duplicateTheme(parentTheme, name) {
    const themeDuplicate = this.themeRepository.create(Shopware.Context.api);

    themeDuplicate.name = name;
    themeDuplicate.parentThemeId = parentTheme.id;
    themeDuplicate.author = parentTheme.author;
    themeDuplicate.description = parentTheme.description;
    themeDuplicate.labels = parentTheme.labels;
    themeDuplicate.helpTexts = parentTheme.helpTexts;
    themeDuplicate.customFields = parentTheme.customFields;
    themeDuplicate.baseConfig = null;
    themeDuplicate.configValues = null;
    themeDuplicate.previewMediaId = parentTheme.previewMediaId;
    themeDuplicate.active = true;

    this.themeRepository.save(themeDuplicate, Shopware.Context.api).then(() => {
        this.$router.push({ name: 'sw.theme.manager.detail', params: { id: themeDuplicate.id } });
    });
},
```

Comment: Not grayed out, the menu entry is simply missing for the child theme. For other themes there is the "duplicate menu entry"
But good to now that this limitation does not seem to be intended, I will dig a bit deeper.
And it's a admin user ...

Comment: The link to the template was very helpful. There is a 
v-if="!item.parentThemeId" which probably causes that problem?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I can't find any info on why a child may not be duplicated. This check was there from the very first commit. Maybe you could try creating the `theme` record manually and see if there are negative side effects to it. In theory you should have a record for each sales channel with the `theme_parent_id` being the id of the Horizon PRO theme and the `technical_name` of your custom child theme.

Comment: We will try locally to patch this v-if away and see if there are side effects and otherwise make a PR :-)