# Incorrect behaviour while duplicating themes that have parent on Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We are trying to duplicate themes that already have parent themes. We are trying to achieve 4 levels of theme inheritance:

```
aaaa (1st - parent theme)
└── bbbb (2nd - child theme)
    └── cccc (3rd - child theme of the child theme)
        └── dddd (4th - child theme of the child theme of the child theme)
```

Unfortunately, from what we have seen, this is not supported by Shopware yet. Shopware only supports 1st and 2nd levels of theme inheritance. On the other hand, in order to achieve 3 (or more levels) of theme inheritance, we are trying [dneustadt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76579199/962814) suggestion (please, read the full question for better understanding).

However, we have not been successful on that try. We experienced these problems so far:

**PROBLEM #1:** "bbbb" theme had correct theme settings (theme loooots of settings), but "cccc" and "dddd" had not. They have extremely similar data, but settings were not coming along. I'm quite sure it's because "bbbb" had `null` value on `theme.base_config` and was pulling from parent. However, as "bbbb", "cccc" were pulling from parent, and parent (which was "bbbb") `theme.base_config` was `null`. Then, I had to copy manually from "bbbb" to "cccc" and "dddd". Then it stared to work. I believe Shopware is just checking the direct parent. If the parent is `null`, Shopware doesn't go forth and check the second, third, four [...], parent levels, until the root.

**PROBLEM #2:** Same thing happened to "theme_translation". I had to copy manually to all languages (German and English) the appropriate translations. Otherwise won't work.

**PROBLEM #3:** "bbbb" is building the correct css output (theme/[UUID]/all.css), but, for some uknown reason, the "cccc" and "dddd" are not pulling the correct css output, even tho they are extremely similar in everything... I'm almost sure it's also because it's not doing the correct fallback.

**PROBLEM #4:** I noticed that on admin, there is no longer the option to use the parent values.

---

The remaining question is this:

Doesn't Shopware really-really-really support 3 or more levels of inheritance for themes?

Is there anything else that I could do in order to make 3 or more levels of inheritance to work?

Thank you so much for your efforts in helping

Answer (score 1):

> "bbbb" theme had correct theme settings (theme loooots of settings), but "cccc" and "dddd" had not.

This sounds to me like the config inheritance chain is broken. While the associated data is stored in the database, the definition of the theme config is still defined in the `theme.json`. From the parent up to the last descendent, the chain must not be broken or you lose definitions up to that point. Given that your original parent is `@Storefront` and [according to the documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/themes/theme-configuration#structure-of-theme-configuration), the `theme.json` of the last descendant should look like this:

```json
{
  "name": "dddd",
  "views": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@bbbb",
    "@cccc",
    "@dddd",
    "@Plugins"
  ],
  "style": [
    "app/storefront/src/scss/overrides.scss",
    "@Storefront",
    "@bbbb",
    "@cccc",
    "app/storefront/src/scss/base.scss"
  ],
  "script": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@bbbb",
    "@cccc",
    "app/storefront/dist/storefront/js/dddd.js"
  ],
  "asset": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@bbbb",
    "@cccc",
    "app/storefront/src/assets"
  ],
  "configInheritance": [
    "@Storefront",
    "@bbbb",
    "@cccc"
  ]
}
```

Likewise the `theme.json` for `@cccc` should look like this minus the `@dddd` in `views` and `@cccc` in the other properties. And so on for the other children down to the root parent. Granted, if this is already the case, it could very well be an issue, that didn't gain much attention, as the inheritance of most themes is only one or two levels deep.

Comment: (I am a colleague of Matheus) I am wondering if there is or must be even a `theme.json` for `cccc` ? The idea is to just create a theme database entry, not create a new `theme.json` and so on (of course we can create a `theme.json` if it helps, and we still avoid copying the full `bbbb` theme custom SCSS and so on)