# theme.json - configInheritance is not working as expected on Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We are experiencing issues with `configInheritance` entry used on `theme.json`.

Let's say that I have the following inheritance chain:

```
aaaa
└── bbbb
    └── cccc
        └── dddd
            └── eeee
```

This is how (`theme` table) `base_config` and `config_values` look like:

```
aaaa                  (base_config: "mycustomvalue" = "black")
└── bbbb              (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
    └── cccc          (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
        └── dddd      (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
            └── eeee  (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
```

Here comes the problem. If I change the `mycustomvalue` value to `YELLOW` on `cccc` theme, I expect then `YELLOW` to fall on the children themes, which are, in mycase `dddd` and `eeee`, like this:

```
aaaa                  (base_config: "mycustomvalue" = "black")
└── bbbb              (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
    └── cccc          (config_values: "mycustomvalue" = "YELLOW")
        └── dddd      (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "YELLOW", as fallback)
            └── eeee  (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "YELLOW", as fallback)
```

However, that doesn't happen. This is what happens:

```
aaaa                  (base_config: "mycustomvalue" = "black")
└── bbbb              (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
    └── cccc          (config_values: "mycustomvalue" = "YELLOW")
        └── dddd      (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
            └── eeee  (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
```

I asked myself why...? But I found out why. Because, when I run `theme:refresh`, Shopware updates the `parent_theme_id` (on `theme` table), but instead of considering the entire chain, no, it uses the top of the parents configured on `configInheritance` (`theme.json`), excluding `Storefront` theme.

```
"configInheritance": [
  "@Storefront",
  "@aaaa",
  "@bbbb",
  "@cccc",
  "@dddd",
]
```

So, the effect is that all child themes are actually child of `aaaa`. After `theme:refresh` run, see the records on `theme.parent_theme_id`. It will look like that:

```
aaaa       (base_config: "mycustomvalue" = "black")
└── bbbb   (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
└── cccc   (config_values: "mycustomvalue" = "YELLOW")
└── dddd   (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
└── eeee   (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
```

Which pretty much it's not a real chain.

Another great big-big problem we faced is that Shopware only consider the `base_config` from the direct parent, not from the parent of the parent (2nd level parent). That make missing tabs, blocks, fields in case it's on the parent of the parent.

That's the end result we are looking for:

```
aaaa                  (base_config: "mycustomvalue" = "black")
└── bbbb              (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "black", as fallback)
    └── cccc          (config_values: "mycustomvalue" = "YELLOW")
        └── dddd      (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "YELLOW", as fallback)
            └── eeee  (config_values: NULL, so it inherits "YELLOW", as fallback)
```

Is there anything missing? Is there anything we could do about?

Comment: If you think this is a bug, please report it on the issue tracker.

Comment: I think this is mostly caused by https://stackoverflow.com/a/76579199/288568 so I am wondering if a bug report would be accepted as we are already on non-standard paths ?...

Comment: There is also https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-24375 already